# Can I sell my version of Ubuntu?

Tags: legal

I wanna customize Ubuntu mini CD and sell it to companies (make unique Ubuntu version). Is it legal? I mean we will do absolutely different system, but making it from mini cd.

Yeah, I really have FOSS spirit, and I want to share Linux and make it popular. But for live I need money, so I thought I can make different versions of Ubuntu with my DE and some unique things for each company. So that will be ideal job for me.

Comment: I think it is legal. You have to change the name and branding, but other then that..., good luck. [ZorinOS Premium] is just that.

Answer (score 2):

Well you definitely can! Read:[Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing)

But try to keep up the FOSS Spirit, BTW!